# ffmpeg multiple text in one command ( drawtext )

Tags: ffmpeg

how is it possible to display multiple lines on one image

i tried command but it gives error

```
[NULL @ 0203D780] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[in][T1]'
[in][T1]: Invalid argument
```

command :

```
ffmpeg -threads 8 -i D:\imagesequence\dpx\brn_055.%04d.dpx -vf "drawtext="fontsize=18:fontcolor=Green:fontfile='/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='shotcam':x=(w)/2:y=(h)-25[T1], [in][T1] "drawtext="fontsize=18:fontcolor=Green:fontfile='/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='Focal Length':x=(w)/1.2:y=(h)-25[out]" D:/imagesequence/dpx/final_with_text_mod_04.jpg
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need to label each drawtext, you just need to specify that both drawtexts are being applied on the "main" source.  Everything that happens after the [in] tag is applied to the main source.  You only need to label if you're using different filters, since you need to specify what is happening to each filter and when, and then how it relates to the main source.  This command should work for you:

```
ffmpeg -threads 8 
  -i D:\imagesequence\dpx\brn_055.%04d.dpx
  -vf "[in]
    drawtext=fontsize=18:fontcolor=Green:fontfile='/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':
      text='shotcam':x=(w)/2:y=(h)-25,
    drawtext=fontsize=18:fontcolor=Green:fontfile='/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':
      text='Focal Length':x=(w)/1.2:y=(h)-25
  [out]"
  D:/imagesequence/dpx/final_with_text_mod_04.jpg
```

(newlines added for clarity)

Comment: thank you. that worked. Although, I gave a wrong example. input is a sequence, output is a single image. it should be `ffmpeg -threads 8 -i D:\imagesequence\dpx\brn_055.%04d.dpx -vf "[in]drawtext=fontsize=18:fontcolor=Green:fontfile='/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='shotcam':x=(w)/2:y=(h)-25, drawtext=fontsize=18:fontcolor=Green:fontfile='/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf':text='Focal Length':x=(w)/1.2:y=(h)-25[out]" -y -r 30 -vcodec png -pix_fmt rgb32 D:\imagesequence\dpx\test.mov`

Comment: thats great this is my sample for multiple subtitle drawtext and multiple fonts with unicode character persian text or arabic text  C:\Users\taba\Videos>"c:\Program Files\ffmpeg.exe" -t 20 -i "input.mp4" -vf "
[in]drawtext=fontfile=myfirstfont.ttf:textfile=Unicode_subtitle.txt:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:
 box=1: boxcolor=gray@0.9:x=30:y=480 , drawtext=fontfile=DejaVuSerif.ttf:text='@blobblob.Tanzil.ir ':fontsize=38:fontcolor=black: box=1: boxcolor=white@0.9:x=3:y=380[out]" output.mp4

Comment: if you are using additional video filters (scaling) inside `-vf` the scheme `-vf "[in]scale=iw*2:ih*2, drawtext=fontsize..., drawtext=fontsize...[out]"` also applies.